# Vimeo Widget Montage Stacking Vertically

Tags: html, css, vimeo

My question is: How do I get the vimeo widget montage to display as an inline-block similar to an image gallery? Right now it is stacking vertically. No matter what class I try to edit, it remains like that.

This is the CSS/HTML that defines the vimeo widget:

```
<style id="badge-styles">
 /* You can modify these CSS styles */
.vimeoBadge { margin: 0; padding: 0; font: normal 11px verdana,sans-serif; }
.vimeoBadge img { display:inline-block; width:500px; height:auto; border: 0; }

.vimeoBadge a, .vimeoBadge a:link, .vimeoBadge a:visited, .vimeoBadge a:active {  color: #3A75C4; text-decoration: none; cursor: pointer; }
.vimeoBadge a:hover { color:#00CCFF; }
.vimeoBadge #vimeo_badge_logo { margin-top:8px; width: 57px; height: 16px;}
.vimeoBadge .credit { font: normal 11px verdana,sans-serif; }
.vimeoBadge .clip {  padding:0; display:inline-block; line-height:0; }
.vimeoBadge .s200 { width: 100%; }

.vimeoBadge .clip a { display:inline-block;}
.vimeoBadge .vertical { float: none; }
.vimeoBadge .caption { font: normal 11px verdana,sans-serif; overflow:hidden; width: auto; height: 30px; }
.vimeoBadge .clear { display: block; clear: both; visibility: hidden; }
.vimeoBadge .s160 { width: 160px; } .vimeoBadge .s80 { width: 80px; } .vimeoBadge .s100 { width: 100px; }


 </style><div id="badge">
<div class="vimeoBadge horizontal">
<script src="https://vimeo.com/pablokozatch/badgeo/?script=1&badge_layout=horizontal&badge_quantity=8&badge_size=200&badge_stream=uploaded&show_titles=no"></script>
</div>
</div>
```

And this is the CSS that I am using to style the image gallery:

```
body {
  width: 80%;
  margin: 30px auto;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

h3 {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 1.65em;
  margin: 0 0 30px;
}

div {
  font-size: 0;
}

a {
  font-size: 18px;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-bottom: 8px;
  width: calc(50% - 4px);
  margin-right: 8px;
}

a:nth-of-type(2n) {
  margin-right: 0;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 50em) {
  a {
    width: calc(25% - 6px);
  }

  a:nth-of-type(2n) {
    margin-right: 8px;
  }

  a:nth-of-type(4n) {
    margin-right: 0;
  }
}

a:hover img {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.15);
}

a.overlaylogo:hover {
  background-color:none;
  color:#000;
  text-decoration:none;
} 

figure {
  margin: 0;
}

img {
  border: none;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  display: block;
  background: #ccc;
  transition: -webkit-transform .2s ease-in-out;
}

.p a {
  display: inline;
  font-size: 13px;
  margin: 0;
}

.p {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 13px;
  padding-top: 8px;
}
```

The problem can be seen on the page in its current state here: http://pabloshead.com
The gallery I am trying to mimic is above the vimeo widget in its current state.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just set `.clip` to `display: inline-block;`

```css
.clip {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div id="badge">
  <div class="vimeoBadge horizontal">
    <script src="https://vimeo.com/pablokozatch/badgeo/?script=1&badge_layout=horizontal&badge_quantity=8&badge_size=200&badge_stream=uploaded&show_titles=no"></script>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! However, that didn't work. In my css I already attempted that: .vimeoBadge .clip {  padding:0; display:inline-block; line-height:0; } I also just tried to copy and paste exactly what you wrote, but no luck!

Comment: @PabloKozatch create a [mcve] that replicates the problem please.

Comment: I'm sorry, I tried, but the vimeo montage is somehow dependent on the css of the image gallery and I can't figure out exactly how. The example of what's happening is running on my website which I linked to at the bottom of my question.

Comment: @PabloKozatch remove `width: 100%;` from `.vimeoBadge .s200` and add `width: auto;` to `.vimeoBadge .clip a`

Comment: Thank you, that removed the styling applied by the css later in the stylesheet, but I needed that to scale the images according to the width of the page like the image gallery does. surely there must be some combination of the latter to make that work out. I really appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

After many hours of trial and error I replicated the css that was controlling the gallery and adapted it to work with the Vimeo montage. It is not exactly the same, but uses the same approach to create an inline-block image gallery with the desired effects.

Anyone who would like to replicate this script to better display their Vimeo montage is welcome to take it as I did not create it in the first place. Keep in mind that your montage must be set up as horizontal and with the highest image size which is 200px.

Here is the script:

```
 body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.vimeoBadge img {
    min-width:100%; 
    max-width:100%; 
    height:auto;  
    transition: -webkit-transform .2s ease-in-out;
}
.vimeoBadge .clip {
    display:inline-block; 
    width:25%; 
}
.vimeoBadge div{
    margin-right:0px;
}
.vimeoBadge .clip a {
    font-size: 18px;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
  }
a:hover img {-webkit-transform: scale(1.15)}

@media screen and (max-width: 50em) {
  .vimeoBadge .clip {
    width:50%; 
  }
}
```